# undefined columns selected in R?

Tags: r

I wrote the script couple of weeks ago and generate some nice plots for my work. Again I'm rechecking the code It shows error ("undefined columns selected"). I'm unable to rectify this error, Please help me,

all the data I had it in 30 CSV files with (21479 rows, 2 columns)

```
Table 1
Geneid  32_S24
LOC117736868    2649
naf1    945
vegfc   449
LOC117738427    1
tenm3   4393
dctd    857
cep44   90
fbxo8   435
hand2   0
zgc:165520  1

Code-
setwd("/home/cent/cmd/featurecounts/gcounts1")
file_list = list.files(pattern="*csv$") 
file_list
datalist = lapply(file_list, function(x){
  dat = read.csv(file=x, header=T, sep = ",") 
  names(dat)[2] = x
  return(dat)
})
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
joined1 <- join_all(dfs = datalist,by = "Geneid",type ="full")
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(y, by) : undefined columns selected

```
==> 10_S9 <==
Geneid,10_S9
LOC117736868,1809
naf1,697
vegfc,359
LOC117738427,2
tenm3,2882
dctd,719
cep44,73
fbxo8,347
hand2,0

==> 11_S13 <==
Geneid,11_S13
LOC117736868,1962
naf1,734
vegfc,412
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,3054
dctd,573
cep44,74
fbxo8,365
hand2,0

==> 12_S17 <==
Geneid,12_S17
LOC117736868,2461
naf1,917
vegfc,483
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,3842
dctd,971
cep44,81
fbxo8,461
hand2,0

==> 13_S21 <==
Geneid,13_S21
LOC117736868,4985
naf1,1912
vegfc,961
LOC117738427,3
tenm3,8074
dctd,1561
cep44,206
fbxo8,952
hand2,0

==> 14_S26 <==
Geneid,14_S26
LOC117736868,1778
naf1,661
vegfc,342
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,2867
dctd,521
cep44,100
fbxo8,347
hand2,1

==> 15_S30 <==
Geneid,15_S30
LOC117736868,2139
naf1,751
vegfc,372
LOC117738427,1
tenm3,3594
dctd,706
cep44,89
fbxo8,408
hand2,0

==> 16_S2 <==
Geneid,16_S2
LOC117736868,1499
naf1,604
vegfc,254
LOC117738427,1
tenm3,2220
dctd,438
cep44,76
fbxo8,269
hand2,0

==> 17_S6 <==
Geneid,17_S6
LOC117736868,1278
naf1,463
vegfc,292
LOC117738427,1
tenm3,2196
dctd,453
cep44,55
fbxo8,296
hand2,0

==> 18_S10 <==
Geneid,18_S10
LOC117736868,2576
naf1,1074
vegfc,497
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,4555
dctd,886
cep44,123
fbxo8,583
hand2,0

==> 19_S14 <==
Geneid,19_S14
LOC117736868,2026
naf1,775
vegfc,383
LOC117738427,2
tenm3,3221
dctd,794
cep44,94
fbxo8,424
hand2,0

==> 1_S4 <==
Geneid,1_S4
LOC117736868,1188
naf1,394
vegfc,241
LOC117738427,1
tenm3,1763
dctd,433
cep44,41
fbxo8,224
hand2,0

==> 20_S18 <==
Geneid,20_S18
LOC117736868,2278
naf1,835
vegfc,408
LOC117738427,1
tenm3,3476
dctd,784
cep44,100
fbxo8,454
hand2,1

==> 21_S22 <==
Geneid,21_S22
LOC117736868,1886
naf1,826
vegfc,377
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,3032
dctd,775
cep44,74
fbxo8,405
hand2,0

==> 22_S27 <==
Geneid,22_S27
LOC117736868,1790
naf1,674
vegfc,382
LOC117738427,2
tenm3,2734
dctd,806
cep44,62
fbxo8,342
hand2,0

==> 23_S31 <==
Geneid,23_S31
LOC117736868,1716
naf1,652
vegfc,341
LOC117738427,2
tenm3,2766
dctd,424
cep44,70
fbxo8,315
hand2,0

==> 24_S23 <==
Geneid,24_S23
LOC117736868,2548
naf1,985
vegfc,584
LOC117738427,2
tenm3,4389
dctd,792
cep44,102
fbxo8,506
hand2,0

==> 25_S28 <==
Geneid,25_S28
LOC117736868,2066
naf1,703
vegfc,359
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,3358
dctd,550
cep44,57
fbxo8,330
hand2,0

==> 26_S32 <==
Geneid,26_S32
LOC117736868,1936
naf1,720
vegfc,337
LOC117738427,1
tenm3,3182
dctd,676
cep44,62
fbxo8,352
hand2,0

==> 27_S3 <==
Geneid,27_S3
LOC117736868,1495
naf1,520
vegfc,276
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,2306
dctd,586
cep44,52
fbxo8,287
hand2,0

==> 28_S7 <==
Geneid,28_S7
LOC117736868,1645
naf1,572
vegfc,339
LOC117738427,3
tenm3,2396
dctd,506
cep44,71
fbxo8,286
hand2,0

==> 29_S11 <==
Geneid,29_S11
LOC117736868,1682
naf1,498
vegfc,341
LOC117738427,1
tenm3,2487
dctd,549
cep44,47
fbxo8,334
hand2,0

==> 2_S8 <==
Geneid,2_S8
LOC117736868,1857
naf1,707
vegfc,359
LOC117738427,1
tenm3,2904
dctd,531
cep44,63
fbxo8,313
hand2,0

==> 30_S15 <==
Geneid,30_S1
LOC117736868,2243
naf1,774
vegfc,368
LOC117738427,1
tenm3,3605
dctd,615
cep44,83
fbxo8,419
hand2,0

==> 31_S19 <==
Geneid,31_S19
LOC117736868,1967
naf1,728
vegfc,335
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,3371
dctd,868
cep44,77
fbxo8,361
hand2,0

==> 32_S24 <==
Geneid,32_S24
LOC117736868,2649
naf1,945
vegfc,449
LOC117738427,1
tenm3,4393
dctd,857
cep44,90
fbxo8,435
hand2,0

==> 3_S12 <==
Geneid,3_S12
LOC117736868,1995
naf1,694
vegfc,372
LOC117738427,1
tenm3,3213
dctd,656
cep44,52
fbxo8,366
hand2,0

==> 4_S16 <==
Geneid,4_S16
LOC117736868,2698
naf1,815
vegfc,367
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,4049
dctd,913
cep44,90
fbxo8,469
hand2,0

==> 5_S20 <==
Geneid,5_S20
LOC117736868,2269
naf1,862
vegfc,439
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,3607
dctd,647
cep44,104
fbxo8,478
hand2,1

==> 6_S25 <==
Geneid,6_S25
LOC117736868,1445
naf1,515
vegfc,232
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,1979
dctd,519
cep44,47
fbxo8,314
hand2,0

==> 7_S29 <==
Geneid,7_S29
LOC117736868,2207
naf1,833
vegfc,386
LOC117738427,2
tenm3,3349
dctd,544
cep44,82
fbxo8,406
hand2,0

==> 8_S1 <==
Geneid,8_S1
LOC117736868,1644
naf1,630
vegfc,273
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,2700
dctd,507
cep44,60
fbxo8,317
hand2,0

==> 9_S5 <==
Geneid,9_S5
LOC117736868,1254
naf1,456
vegfc,299
LOC117738427,0
tenm3,1827
dctd,510
cep44,54
fbxo8,266
hand2,0
```

Comment: I suspect one of your data.frames has a column that is not named `Geneid`.

Comment: That is no the case, I rechecked it. I had the column "Geneid" .

Comment: @park have you accidentally added another unrelated csv file to the directory? If your script hasn't changed and its only interface with external data is the folder, that seems the most likely explanation

Comment: That trues, completely out of mind. Thanks!